# Data from AspNetUsers table error and "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to list `UserId` and `UserName` columns from `AspNetUsers` table into my Admin Area's `EditProfile` view.

My EditProfile model is:

```
namespace AdminPanelExercises1.Areas.admin.Models
{
   public class EditProfileModel
   {
      public int ID { get; set; }
      public string UserID { get; set; }
      public string UserName { get; set; }
      public string UserEmail { get; set; }
      public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
   }
}
```

My EditProfile controller is:

```
private AdminPanelExercises1.Models.ApplicationUser db3 = new AdminPanelExercises1.Models.ApplicationUser();

    // GET: /admin/EditProfile/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        EditProfileModel EPM = new EditProfileModel();
        EPM.UserID = db3.Id;
        EPM.UserName = db3.UserName;

        return View(EPM);
    }
```

My EditProfile view is:

```
@model IEnumerable<AdminPanelExercises1.Areas.admin.Models.EditProfileModel>

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Account Management";
   Layout = "~/Areas/admin/Views/Shared/_layout.cshtml";
 }

 <h2>Index</h2>

 <p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserID)
        </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
    </th>

    <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
    </td>

    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
    </td>
   </tr>
  }

  </table>
```

And also I'm getting error like:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'AdminPanelExercises1.Areas.admin.Models.EditProfileModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[AdminPanelExercises1.Areas.admin.Models.EditProfileModel]'.

How can I fix this problem? 
Am I writting wrong code for getting data from AspNetUsers table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your View is expecting a model of `IEnumerable` (`IEnumerable<AdminPanelExercises1.Areas.admin.Models.EditProfileModel>`) and you are **returning a single Item** from your Controller.

Your View should have a model like:

```
@model AdminPanelExercises1.Areas.admin.Models.EditProfileModel
```

If you are going to show multiple records in your `View` then your controller should return multiple items *(Not a single item, like the current code)*

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm new at MVC. What should I use for returning multiple items form my controller? Because I want to list all my users and userID's from AspNetUsers table.

Comment: You can return `List<AdminPanelExercises1.Areas.admin.Models.EditProfileModel>` from your controller. Fill that list from DB and return it, let your model unchanged. and it should be good.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I will do it like your advice.